# Doctrine2: SUM in left join

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, dql

I need a query with Doctrine, but I don't know how to do it.

What I need is the amount to pay

I have two tables:

Order
OrderItems

I want to sum all prices of order items and after subtract paid, coupon and user_credit from orders.

```
Order
| ID |      Paid |     Coupon | UserCredit |
|----|-----------|------------|------------|
|  1 |     25.00 |      50.00 |      15.00 |
|  2 |     50.00 |       0.00 |      10.00 |

OrderItems
| ID | OrderID | Qty | SinglePrice |   Price |
|----|---------|-----|-------------|---------|
|  1 |       1 |   2 |       50.00 |  100.00 |
|  2 |       1 |   1 |      100.00 |  100.00 |
|  3 |       2 |   1 |      150.00 |  150.00 |
```

I need sum of all: 200.00

1: 200 - 25 - 50 - 15 = 110

2: 150 - 50 - 0  - 10 =  90

```
$query = $this->entityQueryBuilder()
    ->select('(SUM(oi.price) - o.paid - o.coupon - o.user_credit) AS total')
    ->from(Order::class, 'o')
    ->leftJoin('o.items', 'oi')
    ->where('o.config = :config')
    ->andWhere('o.status < :status')
    ->setParameter('config', $this->getConfig())
    ->setParameter('status', 2)
    ->groupBy('o.id')
    ->getQuery();

return $query->getResult();
```

If anyone can help me with this it would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Update: With the above query I get many rows, bat i need only one with overall result.

Update 2: I have now solved it as follows. But I would like to know if it works:

```
$query = $this->entityQueryBuilder()
    ->select('(SUM(oi.price) - o.paid - o.coupon - o.user_credit) AS total')
    ->from(Order::class, 'o')
    ->leftJoin('o.items', 'oi')
    ->where('o.config = :config')
    ->andWhere('o.status < :status')
    ->setParameter('config', $this->getConfig())
    ->setParameter('status', 2)
    ->groupBy('o.id')
    ->getQuery();

$result = $query->getResult();

$sum = array_sum(array_column($result, 'total'));

return $sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- use a subquery for the orders
- sum only the order items` price

Try:

```
$query = $this->entityQueryBuilder()
    ->select('(SELECT SUM(o.paid - o.coupon - o.user_credit) FROM' . Order::class . ' o) AS paidTotal')
    ->addSelect('SUM(oi.price) AS amount_to_pay')
    ->from(Order::class, 'o')
    ->leftJoin('o.items', 'oi')
    ->where('o.config = :config')
    ->andWhere('o.status < :status')
    ->setParameter('config', $this->getConfig())
    ->setParameter('status', 2)
    ->getQuery();

$totals = $query->getSingleResult();
$total = $totals['amount_to_pay'] - $totals['paidTotal'];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 
I think I misdescribed my request. I updated my post again.